# How to optimize Google Maps API integration

Tags: optimization, google-maps

I've tried to evaluate my website with PageSpeed and I saw most warnings (Leverage browser caching, combine external javascript...) come from Google Maps API integration.

So my question is, is there a way to use it as PageSpeed would like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, the external js files can change. If you combine them or host them locally with expires headers you may encounter bugs when they change.

Comment: Ok so I can consider the website is optimized despite PageSpeed warnings ^^ Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem with adsense.

Comment: That's right! You can't basically rely on hosting those files on your server, given the fact their versions may often change and, for sure, you want to use the newest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read this article in Google Blog: https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2015/09/map-tips-speeding-up-page-load-times.html

> Asynchronously loading JavaScript on your pages can give you huge performance wins. We have just updated all of our JavaScript Maps API samples and you can make these changes to your site, too. Read on to find out what we did and how it works, or skip straight to Unblocking scripts to see what you can start to update on your site today.